# Angular: How to use result of `.subscribe()` in consequent Observable

Tags: angular, observable

Angular2: I want to use the result of `.subscribe()` in a consequent observable.

This is in order to use the id from the parent subscribe in the nested subscribe.

I've tried using `.switchMap()` first, but this doesn't seem to work.

**This is my attempt:**

```
this.serviceA.getOrg()
    .switchMap(org => this.serviceB.getOrgType(org.id))
    .subscribe(type => {
        console.log(type);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to log the response from switchMap? Like `.switchMap(org => {console.log(org); return this.serviceB.getOrgType(org.id) } )`, this way you can check whether `org` is defined or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try flatMap:

```js
 this.serviceA.getOrg()
    .flatMap(org => this.serviceB.getOrgType(org.id))
    .subscribe(type=> {
      console.log(type);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

try like this :

```
this.serviceA.getOrg()
    .flatMap((org) => {
        console.log('org', org);
        return this.serviceB.getOrgType(org.id)
    })
    .subscribe((type) => {
        console.log('type', type);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`.flatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) instead:

```
this.serviceA.getOrg()
    .flatMap((org) => this.serviceB.getOrgType(org.id))
    .subscribe((type) => {
        console.log(type);
});
```

Comment: Do I need to unsubscribe from a flatMap or switchMap using a takeUntil?

Comment: Afaik you can just `.unsubscribe()` as usual on the reference you get from your `.subscribe()` call.